# Knife commands in chef is not working

Tags: command-line, chef

my knife config was working.  Chef server was updated to a newer version.  the pem files match and the knife config should be correct.

But when I run any knife command..for example

```
knife user list
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:325:in `stream_check': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:199:in `read_body'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:573:in `rescue in format_rest_error'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:571:in `format_rest_error'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:542:in `humanize_http_exception'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:508:in `humanize_exception'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:499:in `rescue in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:487:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:174:in `run'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `load'
    from C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/knife:44:in `<main>'
```

Version of Chef on the workstation is 11.16.0, Chef Server is 12.rc5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with ChefDK.  The cause was an un-parseable value in my knife.rb.  I had copied my config from a Windows workstation to Mac.  So my cookbook path of c:... made no sense and all  config values (including pem path) were ignored.